# Как сделать стрелки slick slider в отдельном контейнере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Как на картинке
нужно чтобы стрелки находились в каком-либо блоке обертке.
А этот сам блок был в контейнере контента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Воспользоваться опцией `appendArrows`

Comment: Понятно. Так как их в отдельный блок поставить?

Comment: Они же будут заместо стандартных стрелок

Comment: Они не будут вместо стандартных стрелок. Это и будут стандартные стрелки, к которым применяются все опции/методы в том числе и пользовательские шаблоны (`pvevArrow`,`nextArrow`).

Answer (score 2):

Наглядный пример

```js
$('.slider').slick({
  dots:false,
  arrows:true,
  appendArrows:'.slider-arrows',
  prevArrow:'<span class="slider-arrow"><</span>',
  nextArrow:'<span class="slider-arrow">></span>'
})
```

```css
.slide{
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:30px;
  background-color:#cda;
}
.slider-arrows{
  border:1px solid red;
}
.slider-arrow{
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
</div>
<div class="slider-arrows"></div>
```